# Comparing equals between 1D and 2D array in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, deepequals

I have two questions:
I am using JAVA programming language and I have found some difficulties using Arrays.

Here are some different arrays :

```
Object [] play1 = {0,3,6};
Object [] play2 = {0,3,6,4};
Object[][] pre = {{0,1,2},{0,3,6},{2,5,8},{6,7,8},{0,4,8},{2,4,6}};
```

**Question 1 :** Is it possible to check equals between play1 and pre using deepEquals? I also know that pre is 2D array and play1 is 1D array.
If I want to check whether play1 is equal to pre, then I might check like:

```
if(Arrays.deepEquals(pre, play1)){
    System.out.print("true");
    }else{System.out.print("false");}
```

Is the code correct? Even though is is possible to check equals between 1D and 2D arrays? Or do I have to use ArrayList? I am not that much familiar with ArrayList. Would appreciate if anyone explain with example.

**Question 2 :** However, if I want to check between play1 and play2, then also the output is false. I want to check between two arrays even though they don't have equal element but if both array consists the same element such as: `{0,3,6}` can be found in both play1 and play2, then the output must come true..

Thanks.

Comment: That would not be an equals method, but more like "contains" or "matches".

Comment: Should {0,6,3} also 'be equal' to {0,3,6}?

Comment: `pre` and `play1` would never be _equal_ as they have different dimensions. Is a 1 cm line "equal" to a 1x1 cm square?

Comment: yes that's correct.. @ Janoz

Comment: I am not sure what you ment by the 1x1 cm and 1cm. but what I want is to check if {0,3,6} is inside pre (so it is), then the output would be true. @ Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Question2:

You can create `List` of objects and check as follows:

```
    List<Object> play1List = Arrays.asList(play1);
    List<Object> play2List = Arrays.asList(play2);
    if(play1List.containsAll(play2List) || play2List.containsAll(play1List))
        System.out.println("founD");
```

For Question1:

```
    List<Object> play1List = Arrays.asList(play1);
    for (int i =0 ; i< pre.length;i++){
        List<Object> preList = Arrays.asList(pre[i]);
        if(preList.equals(play1List)){
            System.out.println("FounD"+preList);
            break;
        }    
    }
```

Comment: I have tried your question 2 answer code but it says: `type list does not take parameters` Why? my jdk is 1.7... Thanks btw for your previous comment @ Rakesh

Comment: Sorry I don't know what happened earlier but its working correctly. Thanks Rakesh KR

Answer (score 1):

From the API docs:

> Two array references are considered deeply equal if both are null, or
>   if they refer to arrays that contain the same number of elements and
>   all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are deeply
>   equal.

From your question I understand that you are searching for a subgroup of the array.

I don't think that there's a function for that on the JDK, probably you have to develop your own function iterating the arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have found my first answer but still waiting for my second answer.